# R - Subsetting a deeply nested list by parameters that are on the lower levels

Tags: r, list, tidyverse, purrr

Hi I have a deeply nested list obtained from a JSON file with a structure like below in which only one participant from several measurements is displayed

```
$ :List of 11
..$ participant    :List of 4
.. ..$ code  : chr "c7caf74b-8665-4c73-b610-70ccb3f2ec0c"
.. ..$ gender: chr "MALE"
.. ..$ height: num 0
.. ..$ age   : num 56
..$ startTime      : chr "2020-07-31T10:30:36.145Z"
..$ title          : chr "exercise_template_builtin_sens_knee_title"
..$ numberOfSets   : num 2
..$ numberOfReps   : num 7
..$ duration       : num 6
..$ rest           : num 5
..$ preparationTime: num 3
..$ activityType   : chr "EVALUATION"
..$ exerciseType   : chr "METER"
..$ repetitions    :List of 2
.. ..$ :List of 1
.. .. ..$ measurements:List of 1
.. .. .. ..$ :List of 4
.. .. .. .. ..$ bodyPart: chr "LEG"
.. .. .. .. ..$ side    : chr "LEFT"
.. .. .. .. ..$ device  : chr "SENS"
.. .. .. .. ..$ data    :List of 5
.. .. .. .. .. ..$ deltas        : num [1:449] 1.6e+12 1.6e+12 1.6e+12 1.6e+12 1.6e+12 ...
.. .. .. .. .. ..$ channel1Forces: num [1:449] 7.27 7.6 7.88 8.55 8.84 ...
.. .. .. .. .. ..$ channel2Forces: list()
.. .. .. .. .. ..$ channel3Forces: list()
.. .. .. .. .. ..$ channel4Forces: list()
.. ..$ :List of 1
.. .. ..$ measurements:List of 1
.. .. .. ..$ :List of 4
.. .. .. .. ..$ bodyPart: chr "LEG"
.. .. .. .. ..$ side    : chr "RIGHT"
.. .. .. .. ..$ device  : chr "SENS"
.. .. .. .. ..$ data    :List of 5
.. .. .. .. .. ..$ deltas        : num [1:452] 1.6e+12 1.6e+12 1.6e+12 1.6e+12 1.6e+12 ...
.. .. .. .. .. ..$ channel1Forces: num [1:452] 6.86 7.35 7.59 7.87 8.35 ...
.. .. .. .. .. ..$ channel2Forces: list()
.. .. .. .. .. ..$ channel3Forces: list()
.. .. .. .. .. ..$ channel4Forces: list()
```

I want to extract all elements and data of that list based on the $device element,

Any assistance would be very helpful — all my attempts until now mostly are with no success and very much stuck.

Thanks

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail?  The `device` element occurs twice in the individual you showed.  If you choose `device == "SENS"`, do you want to have the same structure in the result, or return those two parts separately?

Comment: Yes sorry, I'll try to be more precise, I need those separately since they are measurements for the left and right sides. My goal is to extract them as a data frame where columns are `$channel1Forces`

Answer (score 1):

For something like this, I think it is easiest to use base R methods rather than getting it to work in tidyverse.  You'll probably end up with longer code, but it will be easier to understand and easier to get right.

First you should write a function to determine if a particular element should be included or not.  For example,

```
includeDevice <- function(x, rep, device)
  x$repetitions[[rep]]$measurements[[1]]$device == device
```

Also write a function to extract a single record in the format you want, e.g.

```
oneRecord <- function(x, rep)
  data.frame(x$repetitions[[rep]]$measurements[[1]]$data$channel1forces)
```

Then you should loop over the whole structure, and build up the result you want:

```
dev <- "SENS"
result <- list()

for (participant = 1:11) {
  x <- dataset[[participant]]
  for (rep = 1:length(x$repetitions)) {
    if (includeDevice(x, rep, dev)) {
       result <- c(result, list(oneRecord(x, rep)))
    }
  }
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can test and modify the two functions easily, and you can single step through the code to see if things are working as you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the thing is that although the code ran it produced a list with empty data frames, do you have any idea why?

Comment: That would be a problem in the `oneRecord` function.  Try it on its own with appropriate `x` and `rep` values, and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat unclear to me which output format is expected, but here are several approaches using `rrapply()` in the `rrapply`-package (extension of base `rapply()`).

- Bind the `measurements` elements together as single rows in a data.frame:

```
library(rrapply)

## bind measurements to wide data.frame
rrapply(
  dummy_data, 
  how = "bind",
  options = list(coldepth = 5)
)
#>   bodyPart  side device                                 data.deltas data.channel1Forces
#> 1      LEG  LEFT   SENS 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12       8, 8, 8, 8, 8
#> 2      LEG RIGHT   SENS 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12       7, 7, 7, 7, 7
```

If necessary, we can further unnest columns using e.g. `tidyr::unnest_longer()`.

- Melt the `measurements` elements into a long data.frame containing all node paths:

```
## melt measurements to long data.frame
rrapply(
  dummy_data, 
  condition = \(x, .xparents) "measurements" %in% .xparents, 
  how = "melt"
)
#>             L1 L2           L3 L4       L5             L6                                       value
#> 1  repetitions  1 measurements  1 bodyPart           <NA>                                         LEG
#> 2  repetitions  1 measurements  1     side           <NA>                                        LEFT
#> 3  repetitions  1 measurements  1   device           <NA>                                        SENS
#> 4  repetitions  1 measurements  1     data         deltas 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12
#> 5  repetitions  1 measurements  1     data channel1Forces                               8, 8, 8, 8, 8
#> 6  repetitions  2 measurements  1 bodyPart           <NA>                                         LEG
#> 7  repetitions  2 measurements  1     side           <NA>                                       RIGHT
#> 8  repetitions  2 measurements  1   device           <NA>                                        SENS
#> 9  repetitions  2 measurements  1     data         deltas 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12
#> 10 repetitions  2 measurements  1     data channel1Forces                               7, 7, 7, 7, 7
```

We can then reshape to a more convenient format using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_wider()`, but this seems less useful than the first format.

---

#### Update

The same approach should normally work out-of-the-box when applied to a nested list containing multiple participants as well:

```
## replicate participants
dummy_data_mult <- replicate(5, dummy_data, simplify = FALSE)

## bind measurement lists to wide data.frame
rrapply(
  dummy_data_mult, 
  how = "bind",
  options = list(coldepth = 6, namecols = TRUE)
)
#>    L1          L2 L3           L4 L5 bodyPart  side device                                 data.deltas data.channel1Forces
#> 1   1 repetitions  1 measurements  1      LEG  LEFT   SENS 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12       8, 8, 8, 8, 8
#> 2   1 repetitions  2 measurements  1      LEG RIGHT   SENS 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12       7, 7, 7, 7, 7
#> 3   2 repetitions  1 measurements  1      LEG  LEFT   SENS 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12       8, 8, 8, 8, 8
#> 4   2 repetitions  2 measurements  1      LEG RIGHT   SENS 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12       7, 7, 7, 7, 7
#> 5   3 repetitions  1 measurements  1      LEG  LEFT   SENS 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12       8, 8, 8, 8, 8
#> 6   3 repetitions  2 measurements  1      LEG RIGHT   SENS 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12       7, 7, 7, 7, 7
#> 7   4 repetitions  1 measurements  1      LEG  LEFT   SENS 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12       8, 8, 8, 8, 8
#> 8   4 repetitions  2 measurements  1      LEG RIGHT   SENS 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12       7, 7, 7, 7, 7
#> 9   5 repetitions  1 measurements  1      LEG  LEFT   SENS 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12       8, 8, 8, 8, 8
#> 10  5 repetitions  2 measurements  1      LEG RIGHT   SENS 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12, 1.6e+12       7, 7, 7, 7, 7
```

---

#### Data

```
## dummy nested list
dummy_data <- list(
  participant = list(
    code = "c7caf74b-8665-4c73-b610-70ccb3f2ec0c",
    gender = "MALE",
    height = 0,
    age = 58
  ),
  startTime = "2020-07-31T10:30:36.145Z",
  title = "exercise_template_builtin_sens_knee_title",
  numberOfSets = 2,
  numberOfReps = 7,
  duration = 6,
  rest = 5,
  preparationTime =  3,
  activityType = "EVALUATION",
  exerciseType = "METER",
  repetitions = list(
    list(
      measurements = list(
        list(
          bodyPart = "LEG",
          side = "LEFT",
          device = "SENS",
          data = list(
            deltas = rep(1.6e12, 5),
            channel1Forces = rep(8, 5),
            channel2Forces = list(),
            channel3Forces = list(),
            channel4Forces = list()
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    list(
      measurements = list(
        list(
          bodyPart = "LEG",
          side = "RIGHT",
          device = "SENS",
          data = list(
            deltas = rep(1.6e12, 5),
            channel1Forces = rep(7, 5),
            channel2Forces = list(),
            channel3Forces = list(),
            channel4Forces = list()
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, regarding the expected output probably you are right, the data I provided above is just one nested list from 990 in the original data set I have to work on, so what I need to do is extract `channel1Forces` from every list of the 990 based on the condition of the device `device='SENS'. But I have to loop over the entire data to do that and at the end get a data frame! Again thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can update your question with a minimal reproducible example, since the data is difficult to replicate based solely on what you mention in the comments.